# ESXi on KVM - Can't find network drivers

Tags: vmware-esxi, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install a .iso on KVM using virt-install successfully - however from 2 disk images (one Debain, the other ESXi) I am not able to attain network connectivity.

Here's some output trying to determine why the VM is not seeing the network card:

```
[root@server2 ~]# lspci -v | grep -A1 -i ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NIC Port 1
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331FLR Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51, NUMA node 0
--
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NIC Port 2
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331FLR Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52, NUMA node 0
--
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NIC Port 3
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331FLR Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51, NUMA node 0
--
03:00.3 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NIC Port 4
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331FLR Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52, NUMA node 0
```

I'm stumped - is there something I am doing wrong? I tried the following:

```
[root@server2 ~]# dnf install libvirt-daemon-driver-network
Last metadata expiration check: 3:37:43 ago on Tue 26 Oct 2021 13:32:29 BST.
Package libvirt-daemon-driver-network-6.0.0-35.1.module_el8.4.0+2523+3300d70f.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

FYI I am using AlmaLinux release 8.4 (Electric Cheetah) - fully up to date with `dnf`.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a bridge worked for this, also some new packages installed. I did the following:

Firstly, via def:

```
dnf install qemu-kvm qemu-img libvirt virt-install libvirt-client

echo "BRIDGE=br0" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
```

Then open the bridge file:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
```

Enter:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR=192.168.1.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
DELAY=0
```

Comment: if its solved, please mark your own answer als the solving - else we will be nerved unti lthe end of serverfault that the  Question will be open